# PHPfastcache does not expire after timeout

Tags: php, caching, phpfastcache

I use phpfastcache with these settings:

```
phpFastCache::setup("storage","auto");
phpFastCache::setup("path", '/path/to/some/dir');
```

The `auto` setting results in the use of the `files` driver.

Whenever I call `set` with a timeout the key I set does not expire. I need to flush the cache manually to make it expire. Any ideas?

Edit: Upgrading from version  2.0.1 to the latest 3.0.9 fixed the issue.